# How to change connected class objects

Tags: python, class, object, attributes, magic-methods

My code:

```
class Potato:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.size = r

    def __itruediv__(self, other):
        self.size /= other
        return Potato(self.size)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        a = self.size
        self.size -= self.size / other
        return Potato(a / other)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Potato({self.size})"
pt = pt1 = Potato(7)
pt /= 4
print(pt)
pt2 = pt / 3
print(pt, pt1, pt2, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Potato(1.75)
Potato(1.1666666666666665)
Potato(1.75)
Potato(0.5833333333333334)
```

Need Output:

```
Potato(1.75)
Potato(1.1666666666666665)
Potato(1.1666666666666665)
Potato(0.5833333333333334)
```

I don't know, why pt1 don't have same output as pt? and how to solve it.
Please help

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: You lose the link between `pt` and `pt1` at the line: `pt /= 4`. Even though they come out with the same `size` values, they are different objects. The line `pt2 = pt / 3` further modifies `pt`, but not `pt1`.

Comment: `__itruediv__` shouldn't return a new Potato, it should `return self`.

Comment: `pt / 3` should not modify `pt`. Only `/=` should modify the argument in place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The in-place operators should normally return the object that was modified. The return value is assigned to the variable, so if it returns a new object the variable will be reassigned. Because of this, after

```
pt /= 4
```

`pt` and `pt1` no longer refer to the same `Potato` instance.

Conversely, the regular arithmetic operators should not normally modify their arguments, they should just return a new object. So `__truediv__()` should not reassign `self.size`.

```
class Potato:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.size = r

    def __itruediv__(self, other):
        self.size /= other
        return self

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        a = self.size / other
        return Potato(a)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Potato({self.size})"

pt = pt1 = Potato(7)
pt /= 4
print(pt)
pt2 = pt / 3
print(pt, pt1, pt2, sep='\n')
```